# CSS selector with nth-child consider list of elements like a group

Tags: css

I have `#id_1 input[type='text'] { border-left: 5px solid #FFCC00; }`

they are 8(let's say) in a table 4x2, I want only the ones in the right column to have this style.

I am trying with:

```
#id_1 input[type='text']:nth-child(even)
```

but none of them get the style, with nth-child(odd) all of them gets the style.

It seems to me that the 8 elements are considered like a block and not like 8 elements separated. 
Some hints on how to resolve this?

I put it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gdg612/z13koLcr/2/

Comment: Can you provide your code on stackblitz or smth to clear understanding you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gdg612/z13koLcr/2/